# Алгоритм перехода в другую систему счисления

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык, системы-счисления

имеется следующий алфавит

> A=1; B=2; C=4;

Число 10, например, переводится как CCB, число 7 как CBA.
Как может выглядеть алгоритм, который преобразует число новую систему с наименьшим числом символов (должно быть не AAAAA, а CA) На любом языке ответ приемлем, заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 6):

В данном случае вполне применим жадный алгоритм - сначала набираете делением с остатком наибольшие единицы (C), затем меньшие (B) и потом совсем малые(A).

Типа 11 - сколько можно набрать C? только 2, итак - `CC`, остается 3. Его можно представить одним `B` с остатком 1 - итак, `CCB` и остаток 1 - т.е. `A`, так что окончательно - `CCBA`.

Надо сказать, что такой жадный алгоритм годится не для всех наборов, но в вашем случае проходит.

Думаю, закодировать проблемы быть не должно...

P.S. Так, как вы сформулировали - это задача о размене, но не о переходе в другую систему счисления...

Answer (score 2):

Например на Питоне с использованием словаря алфавита:

```
alph = {4: 'C', 2: 'B', 1: 'A'}
x = int(input())
answ = ''
Keys = list(alph.keys())
for k in Keys:
   a = x // k
   answ += a * alph[k]
   x -= a * k
```

Comment: Не работает, например, `x = 10; answ = 'AAAAAAAAAA'` .

Comment: @nomnoms12, `Keys.reverse()` была лишней, так как базовый интерпретатор изначально расставляет в верном порядке. Если необходимо, то можно использовать `sorted()`

Comment: Теперь работает, плюсанул Вас. Вот только упростить можно. Например, убрать `Keys = list(alph.keys())` и итерировать сразу словарь (будут возвращаться ключи).

Comment: А питон порядок ключей гарантирует?

Answer (score 1):

Просто опишу:

1. дано число X
2. Делим на цело Х на 4: d = X div 4
3. В результирующую строку вставляем d cимволов С
4. Остаток от деления Х на 4: m = X mod 4
5. Берем остаток от деления m на 2: m1 = m mod 2 и частное d1 = m div 2
6. Если d1 равно 1, добавляем в результирующую строку В, если равно нулю, то ничего
7. Если m1 равно 1, добавляем в результирующую строку A, если равно нулю, то ничего

Comment: Пятый пункт неверный. И шестой.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, увидел. Упустил кое-что.... :))

Comment: Да, так лучше :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за подсказку. Мне нужно быть внимательнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Решение на [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7):

```py
ALPH = {4: 'C', 2: 'B', 1: 'A'}


def convert(num: int) -> str:
    assert num >= 1

    new_num = ''
    for key in ALPH:
        while num >= key:
            num -= key
            new_num += ALPH[key]

    return new_num


print(convert(int(input())))
```

*Тесты:*

```py
print(convert(11))  # CCBA
print(convert(10))  # CCB
print(convert(7))   # CBA
```

Comment: А питон гарантирует порядок ключей?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, начиная с версии 3.7. Уточню версию в ответе.